# TH and TD height not setting

Tags: html, css, html-table

In a table I am creating I cannot get the `th` and `td` to take the height I am giving it. As you can see in my code it looks as if the two fields and `th` is filling the whole table height.

Is there anyway to get the `td` and `th` to set to the `80px` and `60px` I am giving it?

```css
#staff-table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
}
th, td {
    color: 303030;
    padding: 10px;
}
th {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 80px;
    background: #F7F7F7;
}
th:hover {
    background: #F7F7F7;
}
tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    transition:.5s; -webkit-transition:.5s;
}
tr:hover {
    background: #09afdf;/*rgba(9, 175, 223, .4);*/
    transition:.5s; -webkit-transition:.5s;
}
td {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<table id="staff-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Print Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Balance</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Georg</td>
                        <td>Reese</td>
                        <td>George Reese</td>
                        <td>Primary</td>
                        <td>32</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bob</td>
                        <td>Synder</td>
                        <td>Bob Snyder</td>
                        <td>Sales</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by removing the `height: 600px` on the `#staff-table` rule

```css
#staff-table {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;      /*  added based on comment, to keep a minimum height  */
    border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
}
th, td {
    color: #303030;
    padding: 10px;
}
th {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 80px;
    background: #F7F7F7;
}
th:hover {
    background: #F7F7F7;
}
tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    transition:.5s; -webkit-transition:.5s;
}
tr:hover {
    background: #09afdf;/*rgba(9, 175, 223, .4);*/
    transition:.5s; -webkit-transition:.5s;
}
td {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<table id="staff-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Print Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Balance</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Georg</td>
                        <td>Reese</td>
                        <td>George Reese</td>
                        <td>Primary</td>
                        <td>32</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bob</td>
                        <td>Synder</td>
                        <td>Bob Snyder</td>
                        <td>Sales</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to define a height to the table itself, so if data is not in it the table still shows?

Comment: @Paul Yes ... updated answer with a `min-height` on the table

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you intended to have that top row be the `600px` then you need to the other ones to their own specific id or class. The `#staff-table` is being applied to all of them first so it's taking on that `height`.

```css
#staff-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
}
th, td {
    color: 303030;
    padding: 10px;
}
th {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 80px;
    background: #F7F7F7;
}
th:hover {
    background: #F7F7F7;
}
tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    transition:.5s; -webkit-transition:.5s;
}
tr:hover {
    background: #09afdf;/*rgba(9, 175, 223, .4);*/
    transition:.5s; -webkit-transition:.5s;
}
td {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<table id="staff-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Print Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Balance</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Georg</td>
                        <td>Reese</td>
                        <td>George Reese</td>
                        <td>Primary</td>
                        <td>32</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bob</td>
                        <td>Synder</td>
                        <td>Bob Snyder</td>
                        <td>Sales</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```